# How do I use my SSH bastion host setup to connect to Postgres using DBeaver?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, amazon-rds, dbeaver

I was able to successfully work through [setting up a bastion host for my RDS instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78095109/how-do-i-create-a-working-bastion-host-to-securely-access-an-rds-database-using/78096692), but now I'm having trouble figuring out how to connect using DBeaver.

To be clear, everything works when done manually. I can connect to to host:

```bash
ssh -i ~/.ssh/cdk-ssh-bastion-rds -l ec2-user public-ip-address
```

...and tunnel to the RDS instance:

```bash
ssh -i ~/.ssh/cdk-ssh-bastion-rds -f -N -L 1080:rds-instance.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432 ec2-user@public-ip-address -v
```

If I fire that last command in a terminal, I can connect to the RDS instance just fine in DBeaver, without any SSH config:

[image: xxx]

But I'm unsure what I'm doing wrong in the SSH tab, since I'm not able to get to to successfully connect:

[image: xxx]

"Test tunnel configuration":

[image: xxx]

I'm guessing it's something dumb, but it's rather confusing at first glance. After searching around I thought it might be setting the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on the bastion host to `PubkeyAuthentication yes` to accept public keys as an authentication method, along with an sshd restart, but that also did not work.

What's missing to get this connection working in DBeaver without having to connect via the terminal first? I'm going to have a mix of Mac and Windows users and would rather have DBeaver (and their keypair) be the only requirement to connect.

Comment: Are you simply using different keys? `~/.ssh/private-key` in the terminal.

Comment: @jarmod No, sorry for the confusion - corrected the name in the commands to match the screenshots.

Comment: You might be running into a [long standing DBeaver issue](https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/14749), there are some suggestions in that bug report on work arounds.

Comment: @AnonCoward Bah...you may be right. Thanks!